# MVC pass two objects to view

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, razor

I am just struggling with passing two objects to my view and then show data out of it. On purpose to send two diffrent objects to a view i maked separated class for it which would contain my two class object to be pased as follows:

```
Public Class CustomModelProjetsTransports
    Public Projects As IEnumerable(Of woitgroup_transport.tbProjekt)
    Public Transports As IEnumerable(Of woitgroup_transport.tbTransport)
End Class
```

Now in my controlled i am pasing by it to a view (i checked and the data is there:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
        If Not IsNothing(Session("LogedUserId")) Then

            Dim userId As Integer = Session("LogedUserId")
            Dim projectsAndTransportsLists As New CustomModelProjetsTransports

            Dim ProjectsPerUser As New List(Of tbProjekt)
            ProjectsPerUser = db.Database.SqlQuery(Of tbProjekt)("SELECT * FROM [mydb].[dbo].[tbProjekt] where Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT ProjectId FROM [mydb].[dbo].[tbUserProject] WHERE UserId = " & Session("LogedUserId") & ")").ToList

            Dim transportsPerUser As New List(Of tbTransport)
            transportsPerUser = db.Database.SqlQuery(Of tbTransport)("SELECT * FROM [mydb].[dbo].[tbTransport] where ProjectId IN  (SELECT DISTINCT ProjectId FROM [mydb].[dbo].[tbUserProject] WHERE UserId = " & Session("LogedUserId") & ")").ToList

            projectsAndTransportsLists.Projects = ProjectsPerUser
            projectsAndTransportsLists.Transports = transportsPerUser

            Return View(projectsAndTransportsLists)

        Else
            Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login")
        End If
    End Function
```

problem is here within View:

this is on top:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of woitgroup_transport.CustomModelProjetsTransports)

  <tbody>
                                                @For Each item In Model(1).Transports.ToList
                                                    Dim currentItem = item
                                                    @<tr>
...
```

when i am executing my application its filling out correctly here:

```
   Return View(projectsAndTransportsLists)
```

but then i am reciving an error when view wants to be shown as follows:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'woitgroup_transport.CustomModelProjetsTransports', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[woitgroup_transport.CustomModelProjetsTransports]'.
```

**Additional question:**

Kepping on mind i have Projects list within my view how to correctly fill in dropdown (the best using bootstrap styles). I am trying like that but still something wrong...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.Projects.., DirectCast(Model.Projects, SelectList), New With { _
                        .class = "form-control" _
                        })
```

its also saying that `Function(m) m.Projects.Name`

`that Name is not exist` - i see only generic list on intelisense like Function(m) m.Projects.ToList ...

Comment: Change the view to `@ModelType woitgroup_transport.CustomModelProjetsTransports`

Comment: thanks thats right -i relased it as well after some time - can you please take a look i added additional question to main topic?

Comment: Only one question at at time - you need to ask a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear about the problem. You are passing a `CustomModelProjetsTransports` to the view. But the view expects a `IEnumerable(Of CustomModelProjetsTransports)`. Remove the `IEnumerable` and you should be fine.

Comment: thx that was right i relased myself after some time - i added additional question in main topic would you mind to look it and help me out how to solve that?